# How to pass object of type `any` with functions in jest?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, ts-jest

I have a code where I am receiving an object from a third party component, so I have marked its type as `any`. There are a few methods of that object that I am using in my code.

```
init(context: any) {
  context.doSomething('profile');
}
```

Now while testing this code, I want to mock the functionality of the `doSomething` method, but I am not sure how can I do that. I tried a few things in jest.fn() but nothing seems to work. I tried something like

```
type ContextType = { doSomething?: (arg0: { val: string; }) => any; }
let context: ContextType = {};
jest.spyOn(context, 'doSomething').mockReturnValue({});
obj.init(context);
```

But this doesn't seem to work. But  Can someone tell me how can I get this working in my tests?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `context` that includes `doSomething` as a mock function.

```
let context = { doSomething: jest.fn() };
obj.init(context);

expect(context.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalledWith('profile');
```